# UIImagePickerController,Check camera

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
   {
      imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
      imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
      imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
      [self.view addSubview:imagePicker.view];
      }
      else
      {
      // UIAlertView…
      }
}

    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:NO completion:NO];
    }
```

I want to put out an alert when you do not have a camera.
IPhone app launch and move in this code. 
But, Crash (This Error >

`return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([CameraAppDelegate class])); > Thread 1: signal SIGABRT)` when run in a simulator.

Why is this?

Comment: Check the debugger output, add a the `All Exceptions` breakpoint in the breakpoint panel and try again. This should tell you more about the error raised.

Comment: Please write that code inside viewWillAppear and check

Comment: Thank you for a lot of advice. And, sorry for my no good English(´・ω・`)

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

Comment: imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:imagePicker.view];
    
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:NO completion:NO];

    }

Comment: else
    {
        // not found camera
        
        // AlertView……

    }
    
    //UIImage….
    //UIImageView…..
 //UIButton...
    
}

Comment: I was able to!
First, I have to clear the "ViewDidApper".
And as I wrote this.
But leave off the "ViewDidApper", Is there a problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use this code and add `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` delegate in `.h` file

```
 if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])  
    {
       UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
       picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
       picker.delegate = self;
      picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
      [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *altnot=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Camera Not Available" message:@"Camera Not Available" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        altnot.tag=103;
        [altnot show];
        [altnot release];

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Create NSObject Class and name it like `ClsGlobal`, or the name you want..

then write `+(BOOL)isCameraDeviceAvailable` in your `ClsGlobal.h` and implement below function in `ClsGlobal.m`.

```
+(BOOL)isCameraDeviceAvailable
{
    BOOL isCameraAvailable=NO;
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        if([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront] || [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear])
            isCameraAvailable = YES;
    }
    return isCameraAvailable;
}
```

Use this class method, It will return YES if camera available else return NO.

Now you can call this method using `[ClsGlobal isCameraDeviceAvailable];` means your if Condition looks like `if([ClsGlobal isCameraDeviceAvailable])`.

This method will help you throughout your project in any controller, You have to just import ClsGlobal like `#import "ClsGlobal.h"`.

Comment: Thank you for your flagging efforts lately.  In the future, if you see an answer that should be a comment, just flag it as "Not An Answer"; it helps the moderators deal with it more efficiently.  Thanks!

Comment: @Mehul I am having trouble applying your class method. Do I declare it this way: `+ (BOOL)isCameraDeviceAvailable;` and then use it this way `if([self isCameraDeviceAvailable]){ ....}`? I am getting errors `Instance method '-isCameraDeviceAvailable' not found (return type defaults to 'id')`

Comment: No dear You can not call class method using self, You can call this using class name.. Let me explain you.. See my updated answer