# declare and access a BOOL class method

Tags: objective-c, xcode, class, methods

[Mehul has defined this method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699256/)

```
+(BOOL)isCameraDeviceAvailable
{
    BOOL isCameraAvailable=NO;
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        if([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront] || [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear])
            isCameraAvailable = YES;
    }
    return isCameraAvailable;
}
```

But I cannot declare it properly and am getting the error

```
Instance method '-isCameraDeviceAvailable' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

when I declare it as follows.

```
+ (BOOL)isCameraDeviceAvailable;
```

and then use it this way

```
if([self isCameraDeviceAvailable]){
 }
```

I suppose I need to declare it in a different place or in a different way. Can you tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[self isCameraDeviceAvailable]
```

is an ***instance* method call**, not a ***class* method call**.

You have to use it like this:

```
[MyClass isCameraDeviceAvailable]
```

Comment: I am using the script from [link](http://brandontreb.com/image-manipulation-retrieving-and-updating-pixel-values-for-a-uiimage/) where there is no MyClass. I guess that is what the author meant when he said, "Before you give me crap about doing this in the main thread, I know. Don’t do these operation on the main thread."

Comment: No -- this has nothing to do with threading. You should really learn the difference between class methods and instance methods.

Comment: "is an instance method call, not a class method call." unless, of course, `self` is a class object, i.e. if this is inside a class method

Answer (score 3):

```
+(BOOL)isCameraDeviceAvailable
```

The `+` at the beginning of the line makes this a class method, which means that you can only send `isCameraDeviceAvailable` to the *class*. If you want to use the method with an *instance* of that class, you'll need to declare it that way by using a `-` instead of `+`:

```
-(BOOL)isCameraDeviceAvailable
```

Or, as Kashiv explains, you can use the method as you have it by sending `isCameraDeviceAvailable` to the class instead. See [*Objective-C Classes Are also Objects*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW18) for more information.